# Python: Multiply two or more numeric_column in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am new to tensorflow and could not find any documentation on how to define operations on `numeric_column`s.

I have 3 columns in my data (say) `col1`, `col2`, `col3`. All have numeric values. I want to multiply these and create a new column (say) 'product`. I tried the following.

```
c1 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('col1')
c2 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('col2')
c3 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('col3')

p = tf.multiply(c1, c2)
p = tf.multiple(p, c3)
```

When I run the snippet (via a unittest), I get

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column._NumericColumn'> to Tensor.
```

How else can I get it done?

Comment: Why don't just multiply initial values? Give us more context please

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904972/how-to-create-a-tf-feature-column-by-multiplying-two-other-tf-feature-columns